# Retrieving attribute field from polygon feature containing point feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, point-in-polygon

I am trying to populate a point layer's field attribute with values from polygon features' attributes that contain point features.

The inverse is very simple:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='point layer's name',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="point layer's field name",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```

I need to do the exact opposite, get the attribute from the polygon feature and populate the points contained in said polygon.

I have tried `contains`/`intersects`/`overlaps`/`crosses`/`touches`/`within` to no avail.

I'm limited to doing this with the Field calculator expression or potentially PyQGIS, no SQL or DB Manager.

Comment: I edited my title

Comment: Okay, but now you have two topics in your title. In the Focused question/Best answer model, an "and" in the title is a flag for an *unfocused* Question.

Comment: Retrieving the attribute in and of itself is all I need to actually populate my field, it really is only one question but I will edit my title once more.
edit: I edited it once more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly make sure that your layers spatially overlap i.e. the same location and the same CRS.

Secondly as it says in the documentation for [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) function:

> The source feature can be accessed with the variable @parent.

So, you can try either this:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='polygon layer's name',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="polygon layer's field name", 
    filter:=contains($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```

or this:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='polygon layer's name',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="polygon layer's field name", 
    filter:=within(geometry(@parent), $geometry)
    )
```

Alternatively you can achieve the desired output with the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-within) and [`array_max()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-max)functions:

```
array_max(
    overlay_within(
        layer:='polygon layer's name',
        expression:="polygon layer's field name"
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi, as I said in my initial post, I have tried already with within/contains/overlaps/crosses/touches and neither worked unfortunately. I'm also not sure how to use array_max() within an aggregate expression

Comment: Sir, They do overlap and have the same CRS, I use that exact same expression to sum attributes for the points contained inside my polygon.

Comment: Can you please extend your question with more details, e.g if you get an error etc.

Comment: I get no error, values returned are simply NULL as if no geometry fitting the filter condition is found. I will shortly edit my post with screenshots explaining my situation a tad better